# Overflow on PivotPage WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PivotMain.Items.Clear();
        for (int k = 1; k < 157; k++)
        {
            p = new PivotItem();
            Image i = new Image();

            i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources/Images/"+k+".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            p.Margin = new Thickness(0, -100, 0, -2);

            p.Content = i;
            p.Header = k.ToString()+".    ";
            p.Name = "page" + k;

            PivotMain.Items.Add(p);

        }
```

But looks like it has its own limitations? No mater how I load pivot items ( Databinding Vs xml, runtime in code ). It gives out of memory exception if items are more then 40.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended not to have more than 5 pivot items, memory consumption may by one of the reasons. You can try loading the image on each pivot tab when the tab is selected and setting images on all the other tabs to null (or removing from the tab), this may help.

If you want to built something like a gallery, I recommend the [SlideView control from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx), it works fine with large datasets.